# Need graphics/display drivers for Intel S1200v3RPS board for Ubuntu 12.x, 14.x

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, display, intel-graphics

I am really stuck with this... Simply cannot **Edit:** *increase* (I can change but not increase) the display resolution. Stuck on 1280x1024. xrandr gives "*Failed to get size of gamma for output*" ...

Tried Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 and 14.10

Got best results in 12.04. Only problem been resolution. With 14.x, Unity desktop was a mess... very slow.

Ran apt-get upgrade and apt-get update and then installed Intel graphics driver for Linux from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0-linux

On reboot, system hangs.

Tried a different set of monitors too.

Did an install on an old Intel motherboard with the same monitors and it works fine! **Edit**: *Did absolutely nothing here... No upgrade, update, driver downloands... nothing!*

**What is it about Intel Server motherboard S1200v3RPS that I need to do differently from a graphics driver perspective for Ubuntu? That is what I think that I have narrowed the problem to.**

Comment: Found the crux of the problem. It is described here in detail: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1316035. Intel Server Motherboard   has the MGA G200e VGA controller which is causing all the problem under Ubuntu as described in the link.  Took me a long time to locate this... Hope this post helps others, having similar problem, save time.